# Custom Collector that cannot work in parallel

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have made a custom collector that uses a MessageDigest to create a hash. In general MessageDigest does not work in parallel. The issue I'm seeing is in the `combiner()` method. It is not possible to combine two MessageDigest objects. When I return null it seems to work but if I throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` it fails. What is the typical way to implement a collector that doesn't support parallel operations?

```java
class ChecksumCollector implements Collector<String, MessageDigest, ByteBuffer> {
    private String algorithm;

    ChecksumCollector(final String algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<MessageDigest> supplier() {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Could not find MessageDigest for algorithm " + algorithm, e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<MessageDigest, String> accumulator() {
        return (md, s) -> md.update(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<MessageDigest> combiner() {
        return null; //seems to work but hash may not be correct?
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException(LineDuplicationHash.class.getSimpleName() + " does not support parallel streams");
    }

    @Override
    public Function<MessageDigest, ByteBuffer> finisher() {
        return md -> ByteBuffer.wrap(md.digest());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Collector`’s `BinaryOperator` returned by `combiner()` will only be used when used for parallel streams, however the `combiner()` method itself will be invoked when calling `Stream.collect()` to retrieve that combiner, in the JDK’s implementation (see `ReduceOps.makeRef(Collector)`).

You thus have 2 options:

- either return `null`, which would cause a `NullPointerException` if your collector is used in a parallel Stream, at the time the combiner needs to be used;
- or return a `BinaryOperator` that actually throws the exception when called:

```
return (a, b) -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
    LineDuplicationHash.class.getSimpleName() + " does not support parallel streams");
```

This second option would be more friendly to the unknowing developer who later changes your pipeline to make it parallel.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how it would work and I wanted to be helpful by throwing the exception. I went with option 2.

Comment: Note that this is just describing the typical use case. The specification makes no guaranty that a combiner is never used in a sequential context. The actual answer should be, if you can’t support all operations of a collector, don’t implement a collector.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't make sense to work with MessageDigest in parallel, but if there would be some operation's in the pipeline that might be parallelized (and the data set has the potential to be *large enough to pay to the overheads of using the parallel stream*) you may consider the option of creating two versions of this collector.

The remedy for your sequential implementation is already provided in the [Didier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143597/17949945). Providing a proper binary operator that throws an exception is far better than simply returning `null`.

For the parallel version of this collector data from the stream could be initially collected to an *auxiliary mutable container* and then the `finisher` function will populate the `MessageDigest` with data from the container. I want to reiterate that will *make sense only* if `collect` is presided by some operations that could be parallelized and input is significant enough otherwise it'll just cause unnecessary overheads.

That's how a parallel collector might look like

```
     Collector<String, ?, ByteBuffer> checksum =
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
                                             list -> digestAndWrap(list, "SHA-512"));
```

```
    private static ByteBuffer digestAndWrap(List<String> list, String algorithm) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Could not find MessageDigest for algorithm " + algorithm, e);
        }
        for (String next: list) {
            md.update(next.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(md.digest());
    }
```

Comment: @DidierL Thanks for pointing out that mistake, I've revised my solution.

Comment: You’re welcome. I’m wondering why you are using `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead of just `toList()` though?

Comment: @DidierL I am aware that `Collectors.toList()` utilizes an `ArrayList` which is the most common general-purpose implementation.  But `Collectors.toList()` doesn't specify which implementation it provides. It's done deliberately so that in the future this behavior might change. It doesn't seem to be very likely, nevertheless, since there's no such guarantee it's better to request the desired collection explicitly.

Comment: But your solution doesn’t rely on any specific of `ArrayList`, so if a future (or alternative) implementation uses a different (better) `List` implementation, why not allow it to use that?

Comment: @Holger To be honest my knowledge of concurrency is still rather theoretical. It took me a while to realize that this is the only way to create a parallel collector and this solution can be helpful. Meditating on the implementation provided by **michid** I come to a conclusion that for this task an *intermediate data structure* requires having an apprehended of the **locality of data** (i.e. be array-based rather than node-based) to have a better memory consumption. `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` fits into that requirement.

Comment: @Holger I know nothing about how this *alternative* data structure will work under the hood. But I can state that plain old `ArrayList` will be sufficient for this task. And I'm if remember it correctly Stuart Marks in one his talks said that if an `ArrayList` is required, that it better not rely on the fact that `Collectors.toList()` provides an `ArrayList`, but use `toCollection` instead.

Comment: But `ArrayList` is not required for your task. The list in question is used for two tasks, first collecting the stream elements into it. There is no reason to assume that the authors of `toList()` would choose a list inappropriate for this task, as it is the very purpose of the collector. A different point of view is that by insisting on `ArrayList`, you claim to know better than the JDK developers, what’s best for this task. The second use is the `for-each` loop in your finisher. Every collection would do, but the JDK developers already know about “locality of data” and performance in general

Comment: @Holger That makes sense, I agree that if at some point in time implementation of `toList()` will get changed the list that it'll provide will be a general-purpose implementation of the interface that in some cases will perform better than `ArrayList`. Thanks for your patience in explaining it. I've changed the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this work you need to regain associativity by reducing indirectly over functions instead of directly over the message digest. Try this:

```
Collector<String, ?, ByteBuffer> checksumCollector = collectingAndThen(
    reducing(
        Function.identity(),
        s -> md -> {
            md.update(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return md;
        },
        (BinaryOperator<Function<MessageDigest, MessageDigest>>) Function::andThen),
    endo -> ByteBuffer.wrap(endo.apply(getMessageDigest("SHA-256")).digest()));
```

Where `getMessageDigest()` is a small helper method taking care of the checked exception:

```
static MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String algorithm) {
    try {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Could not find MessageDigest for algorithm " + algorithm, e);
    }    
}
```

Effectively this defers the actual calculation of the message digest to the finisher.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but there's no method `getMessageDigest()` in the `MessageDigest` class. Probably it has to be static method `getInstance()` that throws `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, which is a checked exception and must be handled.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, I forgot to include `getMessageDigest` in my initial answer. Added it now.

Comment: Now it fits together. It's a very challenging code, a collector with a nested lambda that returns a function. But the fact that it does its job without entailing any auxiliary data structure is creditable. Definitely, that is an interesting approach.

Comment: What happens when this runs in parallel thought? My worry would be that the bytes or functions are out of order and then the hash would be wrong anyway.

Comment: @JohnMercier I think your assumption is not correct. Parallel streams are utilizing `ForkJoin` framework under the hood and terminal operations like `reduce()`, `findFirst()`, `collect()`, `forEachOrdered()` respect the order in which threads are being assigned with their tasks. I.e. results from the different threads will be joint exactly in the same order these threads have obtained their part of the job.

Comment: @JohnMercier In order to test it, you might generate 1000 hashes in parallel with this code and collect them from the list. Then create the stream over this list and find out if they `allMatch` the hash at potion 0 in this list.

Comment: Awesome! Just reading the javadoc again and now it makes more sense to me. I was thinking of accumulating everything into a ByteBuffer and doing the digest in the finisher but that would take up more memory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's one thing about this code. It is obvious that all the data from the stream when `collect` gets executed has to be dumped into memory, like in the case of sorting. And I'm wondering how the memory consumption, in this case, will differ from the situation when stream elements are being collected into the *array-based data structure* (which has an upper hand of data locality)? A function that points to a string and in turn to another function which also has a reference to a string and points to another function - that resembles a *linked list*.

Comment: No doubt there's a hidden cost, the question is how big this cost is? Is it better than the option of collecting data into the auxiliary ArrayList before processing or not?

Comment: TBH, compared to @Alexander’s answer this is just building a linked list instead of an `ArrayList`, with the additional drawback that it relies on recursion (via `andThen()`) for the finisher. If the source stream is bigger than a few thousands entries you thus have the risk of stackoverflow. I don’t see much benefit of this solution.

Comment: "that resembles a linked list." @AlexanderIvanchenko, yes this is a drawback of this solution. 
TBH, in practice I would not use a collector for calculating a message digest because of the various complexities involved. I'd probably just us `Stream.forEach()` instead.

Comment: @michid `I'd probably just us Stream.forEach()` - isn't it better to use enhanced for loop in this case?
 `list.forEach(str -> md.update(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` - this code causes side effects and doesn't bring a significant improvement in terms of readability.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, of course yes.